# WIndows10 System environment path doesn't work after restart

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, maven

I installed Maven and set MAVEN_HOME in system variables, and added it in PATH, as per instructions. Maven worked as intended from cmd.

After restart, cmd did not recognize mvn command anymore. (I did the same on another laptop, and it works fine). I outputed MAVEN_HOME and PATH, everything is there. I also checked registry, everything is fine, too. Still, cmd doesn't recognize mvn command.

I deleted MAVEN_HOME variable and added it again (without any changes), and it worked again! I restarted laptop again, and it doesn't work now. I have to set MAVEN_HOME after every restart, although it's already there.

I googled it, but can't find similar problem anywhere, much less the solution.

Comment: When you're adding it to PATH, are you adding it as %MAVEN_HOME% or using the full path? I recommend trying it with the full path and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried using the full path, but nope, still doesn't work.